# how can I add a custom calendar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-dependencies, android-calendar

I want to develop an application that help elderly like remind them medication time, and I want to add custom calendar in home screen that show the day number and name.
So, how can I add this calendar in flutter?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLU6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

similar to this package, [date_picker_timeline](https://pub.dev/packages/date_picker_timeline)

```
DatePicker(
        DateTime.now(),
        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectionColor: Colors.black,
        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
        onDateChange: (date) {
          // New date selected
          setState(() {
            _selectedValue = date;
          });
        },
      ),
```